# jquery cookies: a new cookie is created on each page?

Tags: jquery, cookies

I generate the jQuery cookie using this code:

```
$.cookie('queueView', 'value', { path: '/' });
```

assuming that the path is set to the root, hence "/". When i go to a different page, and on a different folder level, the cookie is suddenly gone only to find out that it became unique to a particular web page in my site.

What i would like to do is to have that same cookie available throughout the website.

Hope you guys can guide me, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the following to save the cookie:

```
jQuery.cookie('queueView', 'value', { expires: 14, path: '/' });
```

and to read the cookie:

```
var data = jQuery.cookie('queueView');
```

Try to set *expires* on yours.

Hope it helps!